# How use the option -std=c99 for installing R packages

Tags: r

I have problem in installing plyr R package, and got the following error:

```
Installing package into '/home/mousavian/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'plyr' ...
** package 'plyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/share/apps/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/home/mousavian/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
gcc -I/share/apps/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/home/mousavian/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2  -c loop_apply.c -o loop_apply.o
loop_apply.c: In function 'loop_apply':
loop_apply.c:15:3: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode
   for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
   ^
loop_apply.c:15:3: note: use option -std=c99, -std=gnu99, -std=c11 or -std=gnu11 to compile your code
make: *** [loop_apply.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'plyr'
* removing '/home/mousavian/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/plyr'
Warning message:
In install.packages("R packages/plyr_1.8.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL) :
  installation of package 'R packages/plyr_1.8.3.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status
```

How can I use -std=c99 option when try to install R packages from the source by install.packages command?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

### Try **C11** First

The compiler error tells you to choose either **C99** or **C11**.  So unless you're knowingly compiling legacy code, try **C11** first. You can always then try the legacy **C99** if that doesn't work.

### Use `withr::with_makevars`

Editing individual package Makevars or coordinating global changes to your include/lib directories for every package that doesn't directly compile from source is not a happy strategy for the future. Don't do that! A great alternative to editing your R's `make` configuration is to use [`withr::with_makevars`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/withr/versions/2.1.2/topics/with_makevars) to manipulate the `Makevars` only for the installation command:

```
library(withr)

with_makevars(c(PKG_CFLAGS = "-std=c11"), 
              install.packages("plyr", repos = NULL, type = "source"), 
              assignment = "+=")
```

Plus, you likely already have `withr` installed since it's a `devtools` dependency.

Comment: what does the assignment parameter do?

Comment: @RichardDiSalvo the `+=` is append to any existing value that might be assigned to the `PKG_CFLAGS` variable in the actual `MAKEVARS` file in the package. The alternative is to overwrite it with `assignment="="`. I'm not exactly sure what the other options (`":="`, `"?="`) do.

Comment: I'm getting the same error messages as the OP installing the `cubature` package. However when I run your code I get the error: `Warning: invalid package ‘cubature’` followed by `Error: ERROR: no packages specified`.

Comment: @RobertF did you see this, i.e., try `"-std=gnu99"` instead?: https://github.com/bnaras/cubature/issues/30#issuecomment-794497275

Answer (score 11):

If not already existing, create a directory in your $HOME (`/home/mousavian/.R` in your case). Inside, create a `Makevars` file (no extension). Edit this file with your favorite editor and write:

```
CC = gcc -std=c99
```

Then, save it and after starting R, simply run

```
install.packages("plyr", dependencies = TRUE)
```

It should compile with `gcc -std=c99`.

Comment: I couldn't create .R folder, do you mean folder with name "R" or ".R"? Makevars file is a text file with the name of "Makevars.txt"?

Comment: I said `.R` and `Makevars`.   `mkdir .R`, `cd .R`, `nano Makevars` or `vi Makevars`.

Comment: mkdir: cannot create directory `.R': File exists

Comment: Really! Then use it! Waste of time'

Comment: I have these folders in /home/mousavian/:

Comment: bio  R  R packages  Thesis

Comment: `cd .R`, `nano Makevars` or `vi Makevars`

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much.

Comment: I noticed you never accepted any useful answer to any of your question. It is considered as good manner on this site to do so.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it's quite bad advice.  It advocates users *globally* change their R configuration to interpret all C source code to be **C99**, for all packages, in perpetuity. If all you have is a hammer...you should probably shop around for other tools.

Answer (score 1):

The default `/etc/R/Makeconf` includes `CC = gcc -std=gnu99` (R 3.3.2 and probably most or all other recent versions, although I think the in-progress development version jumps up into the 21st century)

The accepted answer may well work, but is not the `R` default. Setting `CC=gcc` with no other options would drop this default, and this another reason for getting this error. Best to leave defaults alone unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum, to possibly save someone a few minutes: I ran into a similar issue after an R update to 3.3.2 on an Rstudio server (that I have no control over), but with g++. Compiler options for g++ may be added to `Makevars` like this:

```
CXX1XSTD = -std=gnu++11
```

(the package I needed to compile required gnu++11)