# C99 mode error when installing rlang on centos7

Tags: r, c, dockerfile, centos7, c99

I have created a docker image based on Centos7 and installed R with the Dockerfile below:

```
FROM centos:7

ENV TZ=Etc/UTC

# OS Dependencies
RUN yum install -y \
    epel-release \
    centos-release-scl-rh \
    openblas-Rblas \
    devtoolset-8-toolchain \
    tre-devel \
    wget \
    libcurl-devel \
    && yum group install -y "Development Tools"

# Install R
RUN yum install -y \
    http://springdale.princeton.edu/data/springdale/7/x86_64/os/Computational/libRmath-devel-4.0.2-1.sdl7.x86_64.rpm \
    http://springdale.princeton.edu/data/springdale/7/x86_64/os/Computational/libRmath-4.0.2-1.sdl7.x86_64.rpm \
    http://springdale.princeton.edu/data/springdale/7/x86_64/os/Computational/R-java-devel-4.0.2-1.sdl7.x86_64.rpm \
    http://springdale.princeton.edu/data/springdale/7/x86_64/os/Computational/R-devel-4.0.2-1.sdl7.x86_64.rpm \
    http://springdale.princeton.edu/data/springdale/7/x86_64/os/Computational/R-core-devel-4.0.2-1.sdl7.x86_64.rpm \
    http://springdale.princeton.edu/data/springdale/7/x86_64/os/Computational/R-core-4.0.2-1.sdl7.x86_64.rpm
```

I am trying to install the R package `rlang` but am getting an error related to "C99" mode that I cannot resolve.

```r
> install.packages("rlang", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.org")
Installing package into '/usr/lib64/R/library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.org/src/contrib/rlang_0.4.10.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 915685 bytes (894 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 894 KB

* installing *source* package 'rlang' ...
** package 'rlang' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG -I./lib/  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c capture.c -o capture.o
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG -I./lib/  -I/usr/local/include  -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c export.c -o export.o
In file included from export.c:1:0:
export/exported.c: In function 'rlang_env_bind_list':
export/exported.c:93:3: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
   for (r_ssize i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
   ^
export/exported.c:93:3: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
In file included from export.c:1:0:
export/exported.c: In function 'rlang_is_string':
export/exported.c:572:3: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
   for (r_ssize i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
   ^
make: *** [export.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rlang'
* removing '/usr/lib64/R/library/rlang'

The downloaded source packages are in
        '/tmp/RtmpEmr8lk/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("rlang", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.org") :
  installation of package 'rlang' had non-zero exit status
2: In file.create(f.tg) :
  cannot create file '/usr/share/doc/R-4.0.2/html/packages.html', reason 'No such file or directory'
3: In make.packages.html(.Library) : cannot update HTML package index
```

The error is the same one as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198301/how-use-the-option-std-c99-for-installing-r-packages), but I was looking for a solution that I could implement during image build (i.e. an environment var or change to an R config file) that would be persistent for those using the image and installing R packages in the future, allowing them to install with a simple call to `install.packages()` rather than having to use `withr::with_makevars()` for every package install.

Comment: Can you use a CentOS8 image instead?

Comment: @dbush unfortunately I can't due to the availability of some other dependencies (I don't know the details, that is just what I've been told by the SA).

Comment: does setting the envvar `CFLAGS="-std=c99"` help?

Answer (score 0):

You can set R's config file under `$R_HOME/etc/Makeconf` (or add a Makevars in the same directory). By default, `R_HOME` should be in `/usr/lib64/R`, although you can get it in R by running `> R.home()`.

Set `CC = gcc -std=c11` (or whatever standard you like), you may also want to set CXX standard similarly.

---

Technically, you can also change what the gcc binary points to. I tried this after setting the CFLAGS environment variable failed. For example, you can rename the gcc binary (usually under `/usr/bin`) to something like `gcc-v4.8.5`. Then create a file called `gcc` (with proper exec permissions) in the same folder with the following shell script

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
gcc-v4.8.5 -std=c99 "$@"
```

This will work by invoking `gcc` with that extra parameter but it's not recommended since it will probably break after updates to `gcc`. That said, I am not sure what happens to Makevars/Makeconf when R will be updated.

This shouldn't be a problem if the user runs `gcc` separately, it just sets the default standard that will be ignored if the user specifies the flag as well (since it will appear later in the command).